# Why won't my python code print?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm extremely new to programming, and I'm having troubles getting my code to print. The error it continues to give is:

```
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation (<wingdb_compile>, line 5
```

My code is:

```
def main ():

        name = ____________("Tell me your name please ")
        num = int(input("Enter a number "))
    print(name,"your number is", num)
    d1 = num // ______________
    num = num _________  100
    d2 = _________________
    d3 = _________________

    print("The number reversed is ", d3, d2, d1, ________________)

main()
```

So as I said, I'm so new it may be a silly typing error. It has blanks since my professor gave us this much to start, but since I've not actually had the class to learn it yet, I'm a bit stuck. I'm trying to get it to say:

```
Tell me your name please Debby
Enter a number 849
Debby your number is 849
The number reversed is 948
```

Line 5 is `def main ():`.

Comment: Take a look at how Stack Overflow rendered your post; see something interesting about how most of `main()` is not indented with some of the other lines?

Answer (score 2):

It is a type error, very inconsistent use of indentation, this will confuse python.

It should look more like this:

```
def main ():
    name = ____________("Tell me your name please ")
    num = int(input("Enter a number "))
    print(name,"your number is", num)
    d1 = num // ______________
    num = num _________  100
    d2 = _________________
    d3 = _________________
    print("The number reversed is ", d3, d2, d1, ________________)

main()
```

A general rule to follow is after a colon `:` the next line should indented with `tab` once more than the line above it. This gets especially important when using `if/elif` and `try/except` blocks within a function.

I've included some pseudo script just to show what I mean

```
def foo():
    for var in list:
        if var in bar:
            print "var is in bar"
        elif var in some_list:
            try:
                some_function(var)
            except:
                print "error"
                continue
```

Notice how after each line that ends with `:` the next line is indented again.

Comment: I fixed the error of indenting, but it seems like any time I fix one thing, another error pops up. Now whenever I define a variable it says I don't. I'll just take a bad grade and try to understand from the professor though, since the two times I've tried to ask for help over the years I get negative rep. Thanks for explaining the indentation rules though!

Comment: Never tried reddit but I'll look into it. Thanks (:

Comment: @SierraRitter If this solved the indenting error that the question was specifically about, could you please accept this answer by pressing the green check mark?

Answer (score 0):

You are using tabs for the lines with less indentation, spaces for the others.

Don't do that. To avoid this problem, in Wing IDE [adjust your indentation preferences](https://wingware.com/doc/edit/indentation-prefs) to use only spaces, and use the [indentation manager](https://wingware.com/doc/edit/indentation-manager) to repair this file.

Answer (score 0):

print should be within the function, your indentation is inconsistent so python doesn't even know the print function is there. Also it should look more like print('this is what it prints')